# How to open SQLite db in android device from Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I've created an a database in my ionic app and can actually insert and count records from it. What I need is to be able to see the actual database itself so I can access the data inside it. Where is it in my ionic application inside the android device? Please see below code to see how I created and save the database.

```
generateDatabase() {
    var createTableScript = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS lcs' +
      '(rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, entry_plaza TEXT, exit_plaza TEXT, vehicle_class TEXT, user_badge TEXT, scan_time TEXT, toll_fee TEXT, scanned_code TEXT)';
    this.sqlite.create({
      name: 'lcs.db',
      location: 'default'
    }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
      db.executeSql(createTableScript, {})
        .then(() => {
          this.presentAlert('Database created', '');
        }).catch(e => {
          this.presentAlert('Error in executing database script', e);
        })
    }).catch(e => {
      this.presentAlert('Error in the create method', e);
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to see the SQLite Database.You have to write some code to extract the SQLite Database from your application and then need to view it using [DB Browser for SQLite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

To Extract the Database from your application look at the below code:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, function (fileSystem) {
$log.log('resolveLocalFileSystemURL - externalRootDirectory success: ', fileSystem);
//var mainDir = 'Backup';
var mainDir = 'MyAppDB/' + 'Backup' + '';
$log.log('Main dir', mainDir);
fileSystem.getDirectory(mainDir, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (dir) {
  $log.log('getDirectory success: ', dir);
});
});
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory, function (fileSystem) {
$log.log('resolveLocalFileSystemURL - externalRootDirectory success: ', fileSystem);
var mainDir = 'MyAppDB/' + 'Backup' + '';
$log.log('Main dir', mainDir);
fileSystem.getDirectory(mainDir, {create: true, exclusive: false}, function (dir) {
  $log.log('getDirectory success: ', dir);
  var URI_DB = cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + 'databases/';
  var ROOT_DIR = 'file://mnt/sdcard/';
  var PARENT_DIR = ROOT_DIR + mainDir + '/';
  var NAME_DB = 'DB.db';
  var NEW_NAME_BACKUP = today.toString() + '_' + 'MYApp.db';
  $log.log('parent directory', PARENT_DIR);
  $log.log('backup name', NEW_NAME_BACKUP);
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(URI_DB + NAME_DB, function (fs) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(PARENT_DIR, function (directoryEntry) {
      fs.copyTo(directoryEntry, NEW_NAME_BACKUP, function () {
        $log.log('The database backup was successful.');
        localforage.setItem('dbbackup', today);
        q.resolve('success');
      });
    }, failFiles);
  });
});
});
 return q.promise;
```

Failure Case:

```
function failFiles (error) {
 if (error.code === FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR) {
   alert('Message : NOT_FOUND_ERR');
 } else if (error.code === FileError.SECURITY_ERR) {
   alert('Message : SECURITY_ERR');
 } else if (error.code === FileError.ABORT_ERR) {
   alert('Message : ABORT_ERR');
 } else if (error.code === FileError.NOT_READABLE_ERR) {
   alert('Message : NOT_READABLE_ERR');
 } else if (error.code === FileError.ENCODING_ERR) {
   alert('Message : ENCODING_ERR');
 } else if (error.code === FileError.NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR) {
   alert('Message : NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR');
 } else if (error.code === FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR) {
   alert('Message : INVALID_STATE_ERR');
 } else if (error.code === FileError.SYNTAX_ERR) {
   alert('Message : SYNTAX_ERR');
 } else if (error.code === FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR) {
   alert('Message :  INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR');
 } else if (error.code === FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR) {
   alert('Message : QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR');
 } else if (error.code === FileError.PATH_EXISTS_ERR) {
   alert('Message : PATH_EXISTS_ERR');
 }
```

You need to install the file plugin also.